# Mongoose aggregate and append

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Mongo DB (latest version) that I am accessing with Mongoose (v6.5.4)

The project is using a discriminator pattern to keep all documents in the same collection.

There are many instances where i need to join documents.

Set up:

```
// Models:
const UserSchema = new Schema<IUser>(
  {
    firstName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    lastName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
});
// There are other similar models to <Team>
const TeamSchema = new Schema<ITeam>(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },

    userIds: {
      type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
      required: true,
      ref: "User",
      default: [],
    },
});
```

Problem:

I can use `populate` to return collections of Teams and the `userIds` be an array of user objects.

Where I am stuck is querying getting an array of users with an added field of `teams`[].

I've been trying aggregate to no success, I can loop over the users collection and return a list of Teams but this feels wrong and expensive in terms of read units (production data base is on a pay as you go service)

As data models go there is not much going for it - but it is an existing solution

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0):

I was being stupid. The `from` field in my look up was wrong.

Should have been 'teams' not 'Team' which is the model name.